# hello, im getting the following error when making a http delete request

Tags: angular, http, mean-stack

I have got an error:

> core.js:6185 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:2000/delete-post/[object%20Object]", ok: false, …}

Code:

```
public deletePost( _id: string) { return this.webService.delete(delete-post/${_id}); }
```

Comment: Usually you send only a "simple" parameter to delete a register of a dbs, check your call to api, must be like (you give us poor clue): `httpClient.delete('delete-post/"+data.id)` or `httpClient.get('deletepost/'+data.id)` or `httpClient.post('delete-post',data)`. See that delete and get pass a property of the object in the url and post the whole object but not in url

Comment: public deletePost( _id: string) {
    return this.webService.delete(`delete-post/${_id}`);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the whole object in the url

You must have something like

```js
httpClient.delete(`http://localhost:2000/delete-post/${item}`)
```

When you actually need

```js
httpClient.delete(`http://localhost:2000/delete-post/${item.id}`)
```

Basically you want to concat to that url string the `id` of the item, not the whole item

Comment: thanks Bogdan for your time. here is my code: public deletePost( _id: string) {
    return this.webService.delete(`delete-post/${_id}`);
  }

Comment: The thing is that you're usually getting `[object%20Object]` when you're using the whole object. Please make a `console.log()` and make sure that `_id` is a `string` and not the whole object

Comment: i get id as a whole object

Comment: Then your method should look like this

`public deletePost(data: any) { return this.webService.delete(delete-post/${data.id});}`